# Syncing two iOS devices over bluetooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth

I'm not sure if this one is even possible, but I thought that I should ask. I need an event to be triggered on two (or more) ios devices at the exact same time. Right now I use Bluetooth to trigger the event on all devices, however, as expected, there is a small (or not so small, depending on many factors) delay.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or should I forget it?

Comment: Forget it. Special relativity means there's no such thing as "exactly the same time".

Comment: Ok, maybe I was exaggerating by "exactly the same time". To reformulate: Is there a way to keep the error at minimum.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have no reference point, either way I look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how demanding your requirements are, you could use something like the NTP protocol to synchronise the device clocks, and then send a specific time at which each device should trigger the event.

Comment: I'm upvoting just because it's a good theory. Still, I don't think you can start altering device clocks. 

The OP should look at what apps like "Bump!" and such do.

Comment: you can always synchronise your own, private clock - made up of the OS clock + a private offset. Use NTP to calculate what the offset should be and voila!